# Как добавить кнопку изменения цвета поля в интерактивном режиме в 1с:Предприятие 8.3?

Tags: 1с

Проблема состоит в том, что необходимо создать кнопку которая меняет цвет выбраного поля, например, плитка будет выделяться зеленым, а салфетки красным, и можно было изменять, смог только программно добавлять кнопку при создании записи, но нужно изменять цвет уже созданным записям.
[image: Где должна быть кнопка]

Comment: Лично не совсем понял что именно требуется сделать.

Comment: @Sagittarius Вот допустим я создал какие-то номенклатуры, после чего они отображаются как на картинке. Я хочу, чтобы была кнопка, нажав на которую я бы мог выбрать произвольный цвет и выбрав его, цвет поля наименования номенклатуры должен измениться.

Comment: Просто поменять фоновый цвет у списка?

Comment: @Sagittarius нужно чтобы я выбрал запись со скриншота и нажал на кнопку на сменить цвет и в диалоговом окне выбрал цвет, и вся запись например плитка окрасилась в красный

Comment: Если менять цвет по условию - тогда использовать условное оформление

Answer (score 1):

Вам нужно смотреть в сторону использования функции платформы под названием "Условное оформление":

1. https://its.1c.ru/db/v8std/content/710/hdoc
2. https://infostart.ru/1c/articles/181336/
3. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fSAmuUElXGk
4. https://career.i-neti.ru/1s-uf-programmnoe-dobavlenie-elementov-uslovnogo-oformleniya-formy/